# What does this description of a baseball game mean?

Tags: baseball, schedule

The Atlanta Braves are going to the NLCS. The first game in the series is on Saturday 15 October 2021, but the game is described as

> ATL / LAD @ SF / ATL

[image: screenshot of NLCS/ALCS game schedule for 15-16 October 2021]

What does that mean? The Braves are playing the Dodgers in San Francisco and Atlanta?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The date of the game is set, and with Atlanta's win, their presence is assured.  What is not yet known is their opponent or the location.  It's just trying to show the different possibilities.

As a division winner with a better regular season record than Atlanta, San Francisco has home field advantage and would host the first game if they advance.  (ATL @ SF).

As a wild card team, Los Angeles would travel to Atlanta to start the series if they advance to the NLCS.  That game would be (LAD @ ATL).

The slashes show options.  It'll either be the left side or the right side of the slashes.